# Please show me how to convert this button-specific kivy language script to pure python still using kivy

Tags: python, kivy

I have this python code:

```
# (other imports)
from kivy.uix.image import Image

class ChessCell(Button):
    pass
```

& this Kivy language script:

```
<ChessCell>:
    set_hint: None, None
    Image:
        set_hint: None, None
        allow_stretch: True
        keep_ratio: False
        y: self.parent.y - (self.parent.height - self.height)/2
        x: self.parent.x
        height: self.parent.height 
        width: self.parent.width
```

I want to translate this Kivy language script into pure python still using the Kivy library.
So far I have done this:

```
class ChessCell(Button):  
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(ChessCell, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.size_hint_x = None
        self.size_hint_y = None
```

but can't see how to do this part:

```
    Image:
        set_hint: None, None
        allow_stretch: True
        keep_ratio: False
        y: self.parent.y - (self.parent.height - self.height)/2
        x: self.parent.x
        height: self.parent.height 
        width: self.parent.width
```

This must be simple, but I can't see it. Can someone please show me how to convert this?

Comment: What problem are you trying to solve?  Having a separate kv file?   You know you can keep the kv code within your python program so you don't need a separate file, right?

Answer (score 0):

It is a bit more complicated than you might expect. When you use the `kivy` language, python bindings are created for you. In your example, bindings would be created for the `pos` and `size` of the `Image`. Here is some code that I think does what you want:

```
class ChessCell(Button):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        self.img = Image(allow_stretch=True, keep_ratio=True)
        super(ChessCell, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.add_widget(self.img)
        self.size_hint = (None, None)

    def on_pos(self, *args):
        # sets position of Image
        self.img.x = self.x
        self.img.y = self.y - (self.height - self.img.height) / 2

    def on_size(self, *args):
        # sets size of Image
        self.img.size = self.size
```